# how to stop process nodejs within promises

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've created nodejs to trigger(with cronjobs) firebase realtime database as follow:

```
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref('myusers');

var promises = [];

function updateUnlocked(isLocked, locked, msisdn) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (isLocked === 1) {
            var startDate = moment(locked);
            var endDate = moment();
            var result = endDate.diff(startDate, 'minutes');
            if (result > 5) {
                var ref = db.ref('myusers/' + msisdn);
                ref.update({isLocked: 2});
            }   
        }
        resolve('done');
    });
}

ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        promises.push(updateUnlocked(childSnapshot.val().isLocked, childSnapshot.val().locked, childSnapshot.key));
    });
});


Promise.all(promises).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('error');
});
```

Please let me know where can I add `process.exit()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must wait for the "once" callback to get executed. Else the promise array is empty and the process could exit immediately.

```
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref('myusers');


function updateUnlocked(isLocked, locked, msisdn) {
  ...
}

ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
   const promises = snapshot.map(childSnapshot => {
     return updateUnlocked(childSnapshot.val().isLocked, childSnapshot.val().locked, childSnapshot.key);
   })
   Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
     console.log('done')
     process.exit(0)
   }).catch(err => {
     console.log('error', err)
     process.exit(1)
   })
});
```

Demonstrating the control flow.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  const x = [1, 2, 3]
  const promises = x.map(i => {
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve(i))
  })
  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    console.log('done. process.exit(0) here')
  })
}, 200)
```

Comment: `error TypeError: undefined is not a function` on `Promise.all(promises).then(() => {`

Comment: `error TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Function.all (native)
    at /Users/user/Documents/Projects/AngularJS/MyTest/unlockedUsers.js:34:13`

Comment: which node version are you running?

Comment: `v7.0.0` that version.

Comment: does the snippet code work for you (printing "done")?

Comment: did you paste the "setTimeout ..." code to a .js file and ran it with node?

Comment: not working, it's because of promises run before fetching data from firebase

Comment: hmm... but this should not be possible as the Promise.all happens inside the success callback of the ref.once('value') , so snapshot should be an array of your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit on successful completion then refer below code:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(function(data) {
 console.log(data);
 process.exit(0);

}).catch(function(err) {
console.log('error');
});
```

If you want to exit on error as well then add process.exit(1) in catch block.